# any detailed documents about ethjsonrpc

Tags: json-rpc, python, pyethereum

I want to develop a Python based client that can make use of the Ethereum network, a possible way to do it is using ethjsonrpc module, but is there any detailed documents about ethjsonrpc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Ethereum JSON-RPC spec is at: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Some parts of the spec may need to be defined more such as [errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/is-json-rpc-error-behavior-documented).